# Lever Browser Caching on New Staging Server

Tags: magento, caching

We have setup a staging server (subdomain of our main domain) and when we do a GTMetrix report none of the resources (JPEGs, SVGs) have expiry headers.

The `.htaccess` file is identical to the main server - which ironically passes and has expiry dates.

Could this be a Redis cache issue?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! We're going to need more information about your current system before we're going to be able to help you with this. What's your platform, what have you already tried etc.?

Comment: Its Magento. I have tried clearing the Cache but no effect.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?